# How to inject service in custom ClaimsPrincipal using Simple Injector

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, adfs, simple-injector

I am working on an ASP.Net MVC project that authenticates using ADFS and uses SimpleInjector as the IoC container. The service layer of the application is in a different project and services are injected in the controller constructors on startup. One of these services is a user service which I would like to use to get user info etc. from my data layer.

I have a custom Principal (inherited from the ClaimsPrincipal) that I would like to use this user service on and store user information in. The issue I face is I'm not sure how to "*glue*" the user service to the custom principal.

I've tried getting an instance of the user service after each authentication and injecting it into the identity but I get an error saying the container doesn't contain and instance of the service. My code is below:

**Application_Start()**

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        // Register the IoC container
        InjectorConfig.RegisterDependencies(_container);

        // RouteConfig etc...
    }
```

**InjectorConfig**

```
public class InjectorConfig
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Create the IoC container and register all dependencies
    /// </summary>
    public static void RegisterDependencies(Container container)
    {
        // Create the IoC container
        //var container = new Container();

        // Get the assembly that houses the services
        var serviceAssembly = typeof (UserService).Assembly;

        // Interate through the assembly and find all the services 
        var registrations = (
            from type in serviceAssembly.GetExportedTypes()
            where type.Namespace == "MyApp.Services"
            where type.GetInterfaces().Any()
            select new
            {
                Service = type.GetInterfaces().Single(), 
                Implementation = type,
            });

        // Register each of the services
        foreach (var registration in registrations)
        {
            container.Register(registration.Service, registration.Implementation, Lifestyle.Transient);
        }

        // Verify the container and set the MVC dependency resolver
        container.Verify();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));
    }
}
```

My Custom **ClaimsPrincipal**

```
public class MyCustomPrincipal : ClaimsPrincipal
{
    private readonly IUserService _userService;

    public MyCustomPrincipal(IIdentity identity, IUserService userService)
        :base(identity)
    {
        this._userService = userService;
    }

    public override bool IsInRole(string role)
    {
        return this._userService.IsInRole(this.Identity.GetUserId(), role);
    }
}
```

My **User Service** (*In different assembly*)

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
    public bool IsInRole(string currentUserId, string roleName)
    {
        // Check roles here
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Application_PostAuthenticateRequest()**

This is where the error occurs. No instance available

```
    protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest()
    {
        var currentUser = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity;

        // This is where the error occurs. No instance available
        var userService = this._container.GetInstance<IUserService>();
        HttpContext.Current.User = new MyCustomPrincipal(currentUser, userService);
    }
```

I'm a bit of an IoC rookie, so there's probably a simple solution to it but I'm bashing my head against a wall (figuratively speaking) trying to work this one out.

Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated!

**Updated**
Here is the exception detail

```
SimpleInjector.ActivationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=No registration for type IUserService could be found.
  Source=SimpleInjector
  StackTrace:
       at SimpleInjector.Container.ThrowMissingInstanceProducerException(Type serviceType)
       at SimpleInjector.Container.GetInstanceFromProducer(InstanceProducer instanceProducer, Type serviceType)
       at SimpleInjector.Container.GetInstanceForType[TService]()
       at SimpleInjector.Container.GetInstance[TService]()
       at MyWebApp.Web.MvcApplication.Application_PostAuthenticateRequest() in c:\Projects\MyWebApp\Client\\MyWebApp.Web\Global.asax.cs:line 46
  InnerException:
```

Comment: What exactly is the error you are getting? Can you post the complete exception, message and stack trace?

Comment: Hi @Steven, Thanks for replying. I have updated the question with the stack trace.

Comment: Well, the message is clear. Are you sure this the same container? You can view the container's registrations in the debugger. Perhaps your RegisterDependencies isn't called or you create a new container afteer that call.

Answer (score 1):

There are 5 possible reasons I can think of why this happens:

1. UserService class does not implement IUserService.
2. The UserService class is not located in the namespace "MyApp.Services".
3. The class is internal.
4. You accidentally create a second (empty) container.
5. The PostAuthentication method is called before RegisterDependencies is called.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Steven. I ended up resolving the issue with

`var userService = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUserService>();`

Comment: @Andrew If that solves the problem, than there MUST be a second container instance. You should really find why that happens, because it might be causing more trouble along the way.